# How to pass JWT token to Java Lambda function, which can be called via ALB

Tags: lambda, jwt

I have a requirement to pass JWT token to my lambda function in java.

How to pass JWT token to Java Lambda function, which can be called via ALB?

Answer (score 0):

JWT Token can be passed as part of stream or a custom object in handler method. I used input stream and then parsing the input stream to a json and extract the token from event body.
ALB is just a gateway here so does not have a wide role irrespective of what we are using as argument.

Below is the example code:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

JWTSecurityContext secContext;
LambdaLogger logger;

@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
    logger = context.getLogger();
    logger.log("Inside lambda handler");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    boolean valid = false;
    try {
        JSONObject event = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
        logger.log("Recieved event "+event);
        String eventBodyString = (String) event.get("body");
        JSONObject  eventBody = (JSONObject) parser.parse(eventBodyString) ;
        String token = (String) eventBody.get("authtoken");
```